# Trouble with exiting node domain asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-domains

Is it possible to `exit` a domain asynchronously with respect to when it was `entered`? My "stack" mental model of domains is apparently insufficient because I expected this to succeed:

```
var Domain = require('domain');
var assert = require('assert');

var outerDomain = Domain.create();
outerDomain.name = 'outer';

outerDomain.run(function() {
    var innerDomain = Domain.create();
    innerDomain.name = 'inner';

    innerDomain.enter();

    setImmediate(function() {
        assert.strictEqual(process.domain.name, 'inner');

        process.domain.exit();

        // This assertion is failing because process.domain is undefined!
        assert.strictEqual(process.domain.name, 'outer');
    });
});
```

The second assertion is failing because there is no active domain, whereas I expect the "outer" domain to be active.

I'd appreciate an understanding of why this fails.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I shored up my mental model of how domains work:

When I call `setImmediate`, the anonymous function is only bound to the active domain, without any knowledge of the entire domain "stack".

So once you cross an async gap, the domain "stack" is lost, and only the active domain remains.

Comment: not sure about this...I think the domain stack is stored in global space